# How to align my div margin based on other div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Currently it's been tricky for me to align divs based on the other div

Heres my current output.

[image]

But when you zoom out the screen I want it to stay the same.

But this gives me something like this

[image]

The reason why it's tricky for me because navbar is different div from the `advanced king air` div

Here's the navbar HTML CSS

```
 <header>
 <nav class="jet-nav navbar justify-content-between">
<div class="jet-nav-content container">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
    <img src="{{ asset('public/images/header/jetaero-logo.png') }}" class="jet-brand" alt="GNF logo">
</a>
<form class="form-inline jet-contact">
    <a href="#" class="circle-icon"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <a href="#" class="circle-icon"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-black" id="callusNav">
        <small><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;619-562-1950</small></button>
 </form>
 </div>
 </nav>
 </header>
```

**CSS**

```
.jet-nav {
background: transparent !important;
width: 100% !important;
}
.jet-nav-content {
margin-left: 15% !important;
margin-right:15% !important;
margin:0 auto !important; 
}
```

And here's the Middle content div

```
<div class="jet-header">
                            <h2 class="">
                                ADVANCED KING AIR
                                <br>
                                PILOT TRAINING FACILITY
                            </h2>
                            <p class="p-audiowide">
                                THE HIGHEST QUALITY GROUND INSTRUCTION
                                <br>
                                BACKED UP BY ON-SITE SIMULATOR TRAINING
                            </p>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-black margin-right btn-hover">
                                <small><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>&nbsp;CALL US</small>
                            </button>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-black btn-hover">
                                <small><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp;EMAIL US</small>
                            </button>

                            <div class="jet-info">
                                <h6>IMPORTANT NOTICE :</h6>
                                <p>
                                    In response to COVID-19, Jet Aero is taking
                                    precautionary measures to keep all pilots
                                    and staffs safe. All operations are being
                                    conducted with social distancing guidelines
                                    in place by the state of California. Your
                                    training experience will not be
                                    compromised
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.jet-header {
width: auto !important;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1399px) {
.jet-header {
    margin-left: 12%;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1399px) {
.jet-header {
    margin-left: 30px;
}
}
```

Note: Just the portion of `Advanced king air` text that I want to do it. But not the portion of `Important Notice`

**UPDATE**
Tried the answer but this happens

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Just add a common class for a wrapper div  and adjust that class width so they will look aligned properly
Eg don't provide margin left and right use

```
.container{
width:80%;
margin:auto;
}
```

Use this as a common container for both nav and content and don't include the notice div inside the container

Comment: This is invalid css

Comment: Sorry I've updated my css code as i  typed in mobile some case issues happened now try this trick sure it will work remember to remove other margins and padding